# How to convert TYPO3 Typoscript constant file into array or JSON format?

Tags: php, arrays, json, typo3, typoscript

Following is my TYPO3 Typoscript constant file and I want to convert this file into array format using php. (I use Laravel 5.5 framwork).

This is my constant.ts file:

```
settings {
  social {
    # cat=jay: advanced/120/100; type=integer; label=Facebook page
    facebook = http://www.facebook.com
    # cat=jay: advanced/120/110; type=integer; label=Twitter account
    twitter = https://twitter.com
    # cat=jay: advanced/120/120; type=integer; label=Google Plus Account
    google = https://plus.google.com
    # cat=jay: advanced/120/130; type=integer; label=Direct Mail
    mail = jay@gmail.com
  }

  # cat=jay: advanced/120/140; type=string; label=Path to logo file
  logo = 
}
```

What I am doing:
I read this file using

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents(storage_path() . "/jay/Configuration/TypoScript/Constants/Settings.ts");
```

So how to convert this file into proper array or JSON format?

Comment: Do you need it from constants directly, or is it okay, to get it from parsed typoscript configuration?

Comment: Hello @u_mulder Thank you for suggestion.
But I want convert this file json or array format by using Laravel PHP not in typo3.
so how to convert this file using coding? help me.

Comment: Hello @jokumer 
I am used only typo3 constant file not whole structure

Comment: I am not used typo3 but i used typo3 constant file to read that variable and convert into json or array format in Laravel(PHP).

Answer (score 3):

You might get it parsed from a core function.
looking in the API I would consider:

[typo3/CMS/Core/TypoScript/Parser/TypoScriptParser::parse()](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_typo_script_1_1_parser_1_1_typo_script_parser.html#a2daf2f6cd57598ebf37454fac25fbf39)

https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/_typo_script_parser_8php_source.html#l00230